# Where is the "copy video dvd" function on Ubuntu 12.04 Totem 3.0.1

Tags: totem

There was a "copy video dvd" option in dropdown in Ubuntu 11.04 Totem 2.32.0.  How do I get this back in Ubuntu 12.04, Totem 3.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Save a copy" option in the "Film" menu (I'm translating this options from Spanish version of Ubuntu).